# Similar controls/Design as scene builder or gimp

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

I was thinking of building an application like Scene builder but for image editing.

I thought of doing a similar layout design like SceneBuilder where u can drag controls.

Is there any similar controls that could be used to replicate the gui of SceneBuilder?

Or is there any other different designs like a toolbox like gimp.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SceneBuilder code is [open source](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/2872be3a2984/apps/scenebuilder/).

If you want to replicate SceneBuilder's GUI, reviewing it's source might be a good place to start.